# ClojureでGUIを作る良い方法を教えてください

Tags: lisp, clojure

ClojureでGUIを作る為の良い方法を教えてください。

自分が特に良い方法と思うのは以下のような物です。

- Clojureのみで完結する
- GUIビルダ等を使いGUIでUI設計ができる
- コードを書く量が少ない

勿論一般的に良い方法と思われる物も知りたいのですが、上の条件を満たす方法があれば嬉しいです。

今までの試行錯誤では、SwingやSWTを直に叩く方法や、SeesawもしくはSeesaw+GoogleWindowBuilderという方法を試しました。
今の所Seesaw+GoogleWindowBuilderを使っています。

今の方法にも一応満足はしているのですが、何か他の良い方法は無いかを知りたいです。

方法のサンプルや、チュートリアルもあれば嬉しいです。

Comment: clojureのタグを追加しました。

Comment: GUIで設計できるというのはどういう意味でしょうか？IDEで開発できることという意味でしょうか？

Comment: @tomute タグ作成ありがとうございます。GUIで設計出来るとはGUIビルダ等を使い、GUIでウィンドウのパーツを設計出来る事を指しています。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。「GUIで設計できる」の意味がわかりました。

Answer (score 6):

やはり JavaFX が一番良いのでは無いでしょうか？

JavaFX には FXML という XML で UI の構造を組み立てる仕組みがあり、[Scene Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html%22Scene%20Builder%22) という FXML の構築に特化した GUI ビルダもあります。

Clojure + JavaFX + FXML でのアプリケーション構築を試された方のブログエントリもあるので、参考になると思います。

http://tnoda-clojure.tumblr.com/post/54691550227/clojure-java-fx-5-fxml

Answer (score 2):

ClojureScript で良いのであれば

- https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit

でLinux, Mac OS X, Windows に対応したアプリを, Html, CSS, JavaScript(ClojureScript) で作成できます。

LightTable というエディタが上記の方法で開発されています。

また、

- atom-shell

でも同じような構成でアプリを開発することができます。

Answer (score 2):

現時点でGUIビルダとセットで使える開発環境は、

- Eclipse & SWT (どちらもEclipse財団の管理)

くらいのはずです。なので、GUIビルダを使う前提であれば、SWT や AWT/Swing で実装されているクラスを gen-class/gen-interface マクロで拡張しながらClojure本体のコードを書くというスタイルになります。
例えば、

```
(gen-class
  :name myns.ExtendedFrame
  :extends java.awt.Frame
  #_"Follow others")
```

や

```
(gen-class
  :name myns.ExtendedButton
  :extends java.awt.Button
  #_"Follow others")
```

のように実装をカスタマイズしたいクラスを1つ1つ Clojure 側に引き込み、その都度自分の手で拡張することから始まります。 DSL の設計が必要になる時もあるでしょう。

もし、あなたがGUIビルダ(それとGUIな環境)に拘らないのであれば、

- [seesaw](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw)

というよくできた Swingラッパ(with DSL) ライブラリがあります。こちらについては詳しくないので、お時間よろしい時にでもソースを漁ってみてください。

GUIな環境で何度も画面を切り替えながらやるよりかは、マクロを上手く使って、ご自身がよく書き下すコードのパターンをGUIコンポーネント共々局所化または抽象化しておき、必要になったらそのマクロにまとめて呼び出してもらうスタイルの方が、後々捗る部分が多いと思います。

Comment: > GUIビルダとセットで使える開発環境は 
となっているのですが、GUIビルダが好ましいのであって開発環境とセットである必要はありません。また、Eclipse以外にもIntellij IDEAには標準で[SwingGUIデザイナ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gui_builder.html)が存在しています。情報の修正をお願いしてもよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

新しいものでは clojruefxというものが出てきていますね。GUIビルダには対応していないものと思いますけれども。
https://bitbucket.org/zilti/clojurefx

Comment: 質問で提示されている条件に合わない点だけでなく、どのくらいマッチしているか (Clojureのみで完結するか、コードを書く量が少ないか) も説明すると、よりよい (参考になる) 回答になると思います。[こちらのメタ投稿](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1512/30)も参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: そうですね。初投稿で失礼しました。
GUIビルダに拘らない流れとなっているという前提で情報提供のつもりで書いてしまいました。